# Not receiving updated data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I have a getData() function.

```
getData = async () => {
    if (this.state.finalLoading === false) {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
    }
    const miners = await getMiners()
    const results = miners.map(async miner => {
        return { ...miner, logs: await getLogs(miner.minerid) }
    }
    )
    Promise.all(results).then((results) =>
        this.setState({
            miners: results,
            loading: false,
            finalLoading: true
        })
    )
}
```

The corresponding getMiners() and getLogs() functions look like this.

```
    /**
 * getMiners - retrieve list of miners 
 */
export async function getMiners (){
    return axios.get(ROOT+'/miners')
        .then(res => {
            return res.data
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
            return {}
        })
}
/**
 * getLogs - retrieve list of logs
 * @argument {string} miner id of the requested miner 
 */
export async function getLogs (miner){
    return axios.get(ROOT + '/logs/' + miner)
        .then(res => {
            return res.data
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
            return {}
        })
}
```

So, as you can see, I want to getData every 2 minutes. I can see the HTTP requests being made via chrome dev tools however, when passing "miners" into a component (or checking console.log), the data is exactly the same. Without using an interval, I can refresh the page and the new data will appear however, it will not update when using this interval.

Please help.

Update:

```
render() {
    const miners = this.state.miners
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Navbar miners={this.state.miners} />
            <LoadingWrapper loading={this.state.loading}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/:minerId"
                        render={(props) => <DashboardContainer miners={miners} {...props} />}
                    />
                    <Route path="/" exact render={props => <p>Select a miner from above.</p>} />
                </Switch>
            </LoadingWrapper>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Gets passed to DashboardContainer..

```
export class DashboardContainer extends Component {
    state = { miner: '' }
    componentDidMount() {
        const minerId = this.props.match.params.minerId
        const miner = this.props.miners.find(miner => {
            return minerId === miner._id
        })
        this.setState({
            miner
        })
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.miner) {
            return <Dashboard miner={this.state.miner} />
        }
        return ('')
    }
}
```

This Dashboard won't update. Looks like this.

```
export class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            GPU: 0,
            timeinterval: 86400
        }
    }

    handleClick = (num) => {
        this.setState({
            GPU: num
        })
    }

    handleTime = (num) => {
        this.setState({
            timeinterval: num
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { minerid, ownerid, logs } = this.props.miner
```

Comment: What interval?  I can't see any..

Comment: @Keith I'm assuming he's calling `getData()` on an interval.

Comment: Right, sorry.     state = {
        miners: [],
        finalLoading: false
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.getData()
    }

    componentDidUpdate () {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.getData()
        }, 120000)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine in a mock/demo environment:

```js
const delay = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

getData = async () => {
    const miners = await getMiners()
    const results = miners.map(async miner => {
        return { ...miner, logs: await getLogs(miner.minerid) }
    });
    
    //console.log(results);
    
    Promise.all(results).then((results) =>
      console.log(results)
    )
}
    /**
 * getMiners - retrieve list of miners 
 */
async function getMiners (){
  console.log('Fetching miners');
  await delay();
  
  return [
    {minerid: 1},
    {minerid: 2}
  ];
}
/**
 * getLogs - retrieve list of logs
 * @argument {string} miner id of the requested miner 
 */
async function getLogs (miner) {
  console.log(`Fetching logs for ${miner}`);
  await delay();
  return [
    `log1 ${miner}`,
    `log2 ${miner}`
  ];
}

getData();
```

You need to clarify what the issue is. You say it will "not update". The only thing that is outside the scope of this mock is your final `this.setState()`. Ensure `this` is in the proper context, and that setState is actually being called. Wrap it in a `console.log` and ensure it's being set properly.

Comment: Added additional code. Thanks in advance for your help.